# 3D text on QGLWidget in Qt 4.6.3

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt4

I'm looking for a simple way to draw 3D text on QGLWidget **without using FTGL, FreeType, "render to texture" or framebuffer objects**, i.e. using documented Qt 4 functions only, no additional libraries.

Ideas?

P.S. "3D text" means that letters are flat and have zero thickness, but can be rotated in 3D space. Think about ["Star wars opening crawl"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_opening_crawl) - flat letters positioned in 3D space. ALso, I already to know that I can write my text rendering class that would render glyphs onto texture, etc. I'm looking for simple a way to do the same thing using *standard Qt 4 functions*. For example, QPainter probably have access to all required data internally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found something.

[image: picture]

```
QPainterPath path;
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
QFont font("Arial", 40);
path.addText(QPointF(0, 0), QFont("Arial", 40), QString(tr("This is a test")));
QList<QPolygonF> poly = path.toSubpathPolygons();
for (QList<QPolygonF>::iterator i = poly.begin(); i != poly.end(); i++){
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (QPolygonF::iterator p = (*i).begin(); p != i->end(); p++)
        glVertex3f(p->rx()*0.1f, -p->ry()*0.1f, 0);
    glEnd();
}
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

But it looks like I'll still need a 2D triangulator.
--EDIT--

So far I have found no other way to render 3D text using Qt only, and no triangulation routines in library. I'm assuming that this functionality isn't implemented in Qt yet.

Comment: This works fine. Do you know how to fill the text polygones? I tried different approaches with GL_TRIANGLES and GL_POLYGON without success.